# Find an element without an id for Capybara testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have multiple email fields in a form. None of them have an id on them intentionally. How can I differentiate each element in the test if they don't have an id? I'll show code for clarity.

### TEST

```
 it "sends an invitation to multiple users" do
  click_on "Invite"

  click_link "Invite Another Team Member"

  fill_in "", with: "user@example.com"
  fill_in "", with: "user2@example.com"

  expect { click_button "Invite" }
    .to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count).by(1)
    .and change(Invitation, :count).by(2)

  expect(current_path).to eq(account_users_path)
  expect(page).to have_content("user@example.com")
  expect(page).to have_content("user2@example.com")
end
```

This actually creates one object, the bottom field. How can I give the text fields individuality?

### FORM

```
    <%= form_tag account_invitations_url do %>

    <label class="email-label">
      <%= email_field_tag "emails[]", "", placeholder: "Email Address", data: { invitation_modal_email: "" }, id: "" %>
    </label>
    <%= link_to '✚ Invite Another Team Member', "#email", data: { invitation_modal_add: "" }  %>

    <div class="form-actions invitation">
      <span class="button-text"><%= link_to 'Cancel', account_users_path %></span>
      <%= submit_tag "Invite", class: "button button--invitation" %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

## Browser HTML

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use Capybara's method [all](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#finding) for finding all elements with same name:

```
emails = ["user@example.com", "user2@example.com"]
all('input[name="emails[]"]').each_with_index do |field, i|
  field.set(emails[i])
end
```

Or:

```
all('input[name="emails[]"]')[0].set("user@example.com")
all('input[name="emails[]"]')[1].set("user2@example.com")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but can you elaborate on that second one?

Comment: Also I'm getting this error now `Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:
       unexpected ']' after '['`

Comment: @Cameron Bass, you probably need to escape the `[]` with a single or double backslash: `'emails\[\]'` or `'emails\\[\\]'`

Comment: Uggh,.. It's giving me an `Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError:
       Invalid expression: //emails\[\]` error

Comment: To fix an error please try:  `all('emails\[\]')` or  `all('input[name=emails\[\]]')` (updated the answer).
Not clear what do you mean by `elaborate on that second one`, sorry.
I think second example is useful when need to fill in 2 of many options or it may be more readable.

Comment: I meant with that question. Does this replace `fill_in`? sorry

Comment: I think yes, it should do exactly the same as `fill_in`. Thanks

Comment: Now I'm getting `undefined method `set' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: With this solution `all('input[name=emails\[\]]')'

Comment: I just checked, this one works fine (with quotes after name=) - `all('input[name="emails[]"]')[0].set("user@example.com")`. Sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126338/discussion-between-oleksandr-avoyants-and-cameron-bass).